# camel File - Reading recursively from a directory-Does camel use a new thread?

Tags: apache-camel

Does camel use a new thread for every directory it read files from when using the **recursively** option in File Component consumer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it uses a single thread to scan for files to read. Then that same thread is using for routing the file. However you can turn on a thread pool to allow parallel processing of the files.

I wrote a blog post many years ago: http://www.davsclaus.com/2009/05/on-road-to-camel-20-concurrency-with.html - note that since the blog post `async` was renamed to `threads` in Apache Camel.

Comment: thank you . And I assume that if I will use a different route to read from every directory camel will use a new thread for every route , right ? so the recursively option will be much slower than the route per directory approach (I can't use thread pool on the route as I have to be transacted on the route) ?

Comment: Yes a new thread per route. However you can configure Camel to use a shared thread pool among those routes if you want.